# Add Coordinates (from UIViewController) to Constants File

Tags: swift, api, url

I pulled the coordinates from the user in my main view controller like this:

```
import CoreLocation

private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func findCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading
        }
    }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }
```

I then have this URL in a separate file (my constants file)

```
let NEAREST_CITY_URL = BASE_URL + "nearest_city?lat={{LATITUDE}}&lon={{LONGITUDE}}&key=" + API_KEY
```

I need to get the latitude and longitude from the view controller into that URL. How would I pass it there?

I assume it needs to look something like this, but I can't figure out how to compile it without errors.

```
let NEAREST_CITY_URL = BASE_URL + "nearest_city?lat=\(MainVC.locationManager.locValue.latitude)&lon=\(MainVC.locationManager.locValue.longitude)&key=" + API_KEY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainVC needs to set the data into your constants file, as a global variable (since you seem to desire using globals... eek).  Then you can offer a NEAREST_CITY_URL that computes a string using that data.

In your constants file:

```
var userLoc : CLLocationCoordinate2D?

let NEAREST_CITY_URL = BASE_URL + "nearest_city?lat=\(userLoc.latitude ?? 0.0)&lon=\(userLoc.longitude ?? 0.0)&key=" + API_KEY
```

In your view controller:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    userLoc = locValue
}
```

Now it's really bad to have a global constants file like you're doing... at the very least, place all your constants into a singleton class named Constants.  But I'm just here to directly answer your question, so...

Comment: Thank you. I'm fairly new to Swift, but I will look into refactoring my code to use a Singleton class.

Comment: So adding that to my code, it still prints out my correct coordinates, but it still wasn't working. So I printed the NEAREST_CITY_URL and it showed the coordinates as 0.0, and 0.0. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Set a breakpoint at userLoc = locValue and see if stepping over it results in the userLoc changing.  You can also add a didSet to userLoc and add a breakpoint there to see whenever it changes.